# Sync artifacts from Nexus repository to a folder in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nexus, rsync

In my organisation , we have a interesting problem and I am trying to figure out most optimal way to solve this. We have a nexus repository with around 100 files with total size exceeding 1 gb. This nexus repository (version 3.x) is setup on Windows ec2 instance with s3 type i.e s3 blob storage is being used to store artifacts in backend.

We want it to be in sync with a folder in multiple(more than 10) S3 buckets. This nexus repository hardly gets changed and whenever it gets changed we want it to be in sync with all S3 bucket automatically.

This repository contains few installer msi files ,exe files and some shell scripts. It hardly gets changed, maybe once or twice in quarter. Frequent periodic sync can be done but just seems overkill to me. And since files are more than 1gb I would prefer incremental sync. These files are used while actual deployment and we want to make sure s3 bucket of all environments are synced up.

I could write lambda to update folder in s3 bucket but it could take more time than 5 minutes to copy all the files. Hence i was thinking if there is a way to do incremental sync from nexus to s3 bucket ?

Please advise.

Comment: Nexus 2 or Nexus 3? And what latency is acceptable (ie, can you run the sync daily, or must it happen as soon as you push the file)? What's the purpose for this sync: Is it simply backup? Also, is the Nexus server running on EC2?

Comment: @kdgregory: Thanks for your time. Please see updated comments in question.

Comment: I haven't tried this, so it's not an answer, but I think the best solution is to use the [webhooks](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/webhooks) that Nexus 3 provides. You could set up an API Gateway / Lambda to process them immediately, or write to a queue and process in batch (you'd still need  to have something that listens for them). Copying a single file shouldn't exceed your Lambda execution time, even if it's 1GB and goes to a dozen destinations.

Comment: You might also be able to use the [search API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api) to retrieve assets based on a date range, but the online docs don't list the allowed criteria and I don't have access to our Nexus server atm (I know the information is there, but whether it's exposed is another matter).

Comment: @kdgregory: I ended up running a python script as cronjob which calls restapi of Nexus 3 to fetch list of artifacts and "wget -N" them and then aws sync to s3 buckets.

Comment: https://github.com/030/n3dr

Answer (score 0):

If your repository is Yum format (which seems unlikely as you mention Windows), then you could use `reposync` to copy the Nexus repo to a local directory. From there you could use `aws s3 sync` to copy it to one or more S3 buckets (and sync works incrementally).

I'd imagine something similar would also be possible for 'raw' repositories because they're not much away from "dump a load of files onto a web server", but instead of `reposync`, you'd need something like `wget --mirror`. This may also work for some other repository formats, but you'd need to get Nexus to return directory listings, which it generally doesn't seem to do.

One other option you may be able to use is to replicate from one S3 bucket to the others. That way, you'd only need to sync to one bucket and let AWS take care of the rest for you.